# Selenium test failing headless, succeeding in firefox

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, selenium

I'm running Selenium automated tests to navigate through a wizard. Each step has a stage counter to keep track of the current step. I assertEquals the (on the screen) hidden stage element to assert I'm on the right page.

On each page in the wizard there's something to fill in like a username. Then you click next and go to the next page and the stage counter goes up by 1.

The last stage is stage 4, when submitting the final stage, you get redirected to a new wizard where the stage count is 1 again.

The wizard is displayed in a Twitter Bootstrap 3 modal window.

When I run the test in headless mode asserting that the stage count in this new wizard is 1 fails.
It's still 4. I can't locate any element here either. So it seems like this page isn't loaded correctly when in headless mode. 
I already tried Thread.sleep(5000) after every click to make sure it loads correctly. I also tried waiting until an element was present before asserting that stage count changed to 1.
The result was No such element exception.

So my question is, What is different in headless mode that can cause this to happen?

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("ElementImLookinFor")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("ElementImLookinFor")).sendKeys("test");
    driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
    stageElementCheck("4");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("TermsOfUseElement")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();

    stageElementCheck("1"); //expected 1 was 4

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("ElementImLookinFor")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();


public void stageElementCheck(String i){
      assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.xpath("HiddenStageElement")));
      assertEquals(i,driver.findElement(By.xpath("HiddenStageElement")).getAttribute("value"));
  }
```

To achieve Headless:

```
driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);
        ((HtmlUnitDriver) driver).setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(timeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: What setup do you use to run your test in "headless mode"? There are very different ways to achieve "headless mode". (Edit your question with this information.)

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use tool like Xvfb x server to run selenium UI tests in headless mode. Its easy to configure.